# Does Spring AMQP CorrelationData getFuture wait indefinitely without timeout?

Tags: java, asynchronous, rabbitmq, timeout, spring-amqp

In the context of Publisher confirms, when waiting for the CorrelationData's future (SettableListenableFuture#get()) - does it wait indefinitely or is there a timeout configured under the water?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does wait indefinitely. There is just no any opinion and everything is delegated directly to the `java.util.concurrent.FutureTask` internally in the `org.springframework.util.concurrent.SettableListenableFuture` implementation.

Not sure why the question, but in normal situation when broker is UP, it is going to answer to confirm during reasonable finite time. If broker is not available, you are going to fail much earlier than you reach a `CorrelationData.getFuture()` in your code.

Comment: My advice is to never call `get()` without a timeout. The framework will complete the future exceptionally if the channel is closed before the confirm is received, but it's generally best practice to always use a timeout.

Comment: Thanks! I'm dealing with the scenario of a broker reaching the `vm_memory_high_watermark` and thus blocking the connection. I'm trying to determine the appropriate timeout, and thought I might not need it if it threw the Exception itself at somepoint. This because a blocked connection does not result in an Exception anywhere.

Comment: See `ConnectionBlockedEvent` for that purpose: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#blocked-connections-and-resource-constraints